# How to check if a list is empty

Tags: python, python-3.x

My definition of empty lists are:

```
a = []
a = [[], []]
a = [[], [], [[], []]]
```

The common ways are not applicable, because the lengths of last two lists are not 0, and they will be considered as True in if condition.

```
if a:
    print(True)    # True
#-------------------------
print(len(a) != 0) # True
```

Are there any good ways to check?

Comment: So, you have to check it by recursive. if so how many list are you going to embed?

Comment: Sorry, but that's not a definition, those are just examples. The definition is much harder to come by, but let's try. For example, after `a=[]; a.append(a)`, do you consider `a` to be empty?

Comment: @Veky. Yes, according to the examples. The definition seems pretty clear: no elements that aren't lists allowed.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I really don't know what you people call a "definition". That's a _criterion_ in my parlance. But nevermind. Of course my `a` doesn't contain elements that aren't lists, but `[[5]]` also doesn't, and it's "obviously" not empty according to OP. I think the point is that you want to say that it contains just _empty_ lists, and that is just a circular definition.

Comment: @Veky I used "my definition" which means this definition only works for me, but this is not the point...

Comment: BUT IT'S NOT A DEFINITION! :-) Those are just examples that work for you, fine. But do you consider `a` above empty or not?

Comment: @Veky what about this for a definition: *A list of length 0 is empty. A list containing one or more empty lists is empty.* That is sufficiently precise and covers all examples the OP posted.

Comment: of course, but by that definition, [[],[5]] is empty. I'm not sure you want that. :-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function that recursively checks the items within sublists:

```
def is_empty(l):
    return all(is_empty(i) if isinstance(i, list) else False for i in l)
```

so that:

```
print(is_empty([[], [], [[], []]]))
print(is_empty([[], [], [[], [1]]]))
```

outputs:

```
True
False
```

And if you want to handle lists that contain circular references you can use a `seen` set to keep track of the list references the function has seen and skip them when they are seen:

```
def is_empty(l, seen=None):
    if seen is None:
        seen = set()
    return all(seen.add(id(i)) or is_empty(i, seen) if isinstance(i, list) else False for i in l if id(i) not in seen)
```

so that:

```
a = []
a.append(a)
print(is_empty(a))
a = [1]
a.append(a)
print(is_empty(a))
```

outputs:

```
True
False
```

Comment: ... and try it on `a=[]; a.append(a)`, and let me know what it says. ;-P Really, people, the answer is much more complicated, but until the OP says what exactly do they want (I suspect a grave case of an XY problem:), we cannot do anything.

Comment: You're talking about a corner case here. For common data structures the above would be enough. If you want to release this as a production module then yeah you should keep track of the references to avoid circular references.

Comment: Updated the answer with a solution that checks for circular references then.

Comment: BTW "much more complicated" is quite an exaggeration on your part IMHO.

Comment: Corner cases are the best way to show that the problem is underspecified. One thing is to actually write the code that handles it. What I want is just to get to a consensus, whether we consider it empty or not.

Comment: `all(seen.add(id(i)) or is_empty(i, seen) if isinstance(i, list) and id(i) not in seen else False for i in l)` -- exaggeration, hm? :-) And that's your _second_ try. :-]

Comment: Thanks, your answer is really detailed

Comment: @Veky It's logically simple really. Not sure how anyone would find it much more complicated.

Comment: Logically simple?? Tell it to all the people studying nonWF sets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-well-founded_set_theory Note that there are _four_ different widely accepted notions of equality (and correspondingly of emptyness) for nonWF sets. (Of course, lists are also ordered, but I fail to see how it makes them _less_ complicated than sets.)

Comment: I've updated the answer with a more rounded test of emptiness in case of circular references.

Answer (score 3):

Kinda silly, but probably decent solution:

```
if str(a).strip('[], '):
```

or when the `list` might contain itself and that should be counted as empty:

```
if str(a).strip('[], .'):
```

Relies on the fact that `list`s are represented solely with brackets, spaces and commas, but anything they contain (that doesn't have an intentionally pathological `repr`) has *some* other character involved. `list`s containing themselves use `...` when they recurse, so stripping that handles them. So we just `strip` the only characters seen in empty `list`s and `list`s of empty `list`s, and if anything is left, there was something non-`list`y in there.

Comment: What about ellipsis?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: The `Ellipsis` singleton renders as its name, not three dots, because `str` of a `list` gets the `repr` of its contents, and apparently the `repr` of `Ellipsis` isn't `...`. Go figure. I figured `Ellipsis` wouldn't count as empty, so that works for us here.

Comment: Well seen. +1 for cleverness

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Yeah, this is the sort of cleverness that makes me feel a little squeamish, since it's not actually solving the problem logically, but via a heuristic (albeit one that would never be violated by *any* existing code I'm aware of, though it would be trivial to construct a class for the purposes of breaking the test). It's almost certainly the fastest solution in the case of smallish and empty `list`s, but since it can't short-circuit, it could behave poorly for truly huge, obviously non-empty `list`s that a more precise solution could quickly report as non-empty.

Comment: It's also not composable; if you want to allow arbitrarily nested sequences/collections/iterables so long as all such iterables are empty, not just arbitrarily nested `list`s, you can't just expand the set of `strip` characters. That said, if your use case is solely to handle `list`, and the `list`s are of moderate size (say, all nesting included, a hundred objects or fewer with `repr`s that aren't insanely expensive), it's pretty hard to beat on performance, and impossible to beat on code simplicity. We'll call it a [Worse is Better](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worse_is_better) solution.

Comment: Pragmatism is above all

Answer (score 0):

To check each item, there are simple but useful way is.

```
In [65]: a = [[], [], [[], [1]]]
In [66]: mark = []
In [67]: def recursive_check(lst, mark):
    ...:     for i in lst:
    ...:         if isinstance(i, list):
    ...:             recursive_check(i, mark)
    ...:         else:
    ...:             mark.append(i)
    ...:     return mark
```

And then, you can check the global mark value after call the `recursive_check`

```
recursive_check(a, mark)
```

and you can easily check mark value like:

```
if mark:
    pass
```

After each call if you run it on `terminal`, don't forget reset `mark` as empty.

```
mark=[]
```

To make it easy to use, you can add another function to wrapper it.

```
In [77]: def test(lst):
    ...:     mark = []
    ...:     return len(recursive_check(lst, mark)) != 0
    ...: 

In [78]: a
Out[78]: [[], [], [[], [1]]]

In [79]: test(a)
Out[79]: True

In [80]: cc
Out[80]: [[], [], [[], []]]

In [81]: test(cc)
Out[81]: False
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need some recursivity. Try this:

```
  def is_empty(arr, seen=None):
      # Infinite loops detection
      if seen is None:
          seen = set()
      if id(arr) in seen:
          arr.remove(arr)
      seen.add(id(arr))

      if isinstance(arr, list):
          if arr:
              return all(is_empty(b, seen) for b in arr)
          else:
              return True
      else:
          return False
```

Basically, anything that's not a list means your list is not empty. If it finds a non empty list, it starts looking for every element inside it. If there's any element but list in it, it will return `False`.

Edited to avoid infinit loops (thanks to @MadPhysicist !),

Comment: Try with a list that contains itself

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what you mean. Can you send me an example?

Comment: `a = []; a.append(a)`

Answer (score 0):

You need a solution that is not only recursive, but also prevents infinite recursion. Here is one such possibility:

```
def has_non_list(x):
    """ Assumes x is a list """
    seen = set()  # stash IDs since lists aren't hashable
    def check(x):
        if id(x) in seen:
            return False
        seen.add(id(x))
        for i in x:
            if not isinstance(i, list) or check(i):
                 return True
        return False
    return check(x)
```

It should be pretty easy to make this work for any sequence.

Answer (score 0):

A more composable/reusable answer would be to make a generator function that flattens nested `list`s (or for greater reusability, arbitrary iterables), making it trivial to iterate the result; if it yields *anything*, it's non-empty (and you can stop iterating immediately, saving work on potentially huge `list`s of `list`s), otherwise it's empty:

```
def flatten(it, skip_same_list=True):
    '''Returns a generator of all non-lists in possibly nested list

    If skip_same_list is False, this will produce infinite output if a list is
    nested inside itself'''
    stack = [it]
    seen = set()
    while stack:
        item = stack.pop()
        if isinstance(item, list):
            if skip_same_list:
                if id(item) in seen:
                    continue  # Ignores same list if seen again
                seen.add(id(item))
            stack.extend(reversed(item))
        else:
            yield item
```

Once you have that, solving your problem is trivial:

```
def my_is_empty(it, *, _sentinel=object()):
    # Two arg next returns the first item or _sentinel if no items yielded
    return next(flatten(it), _sentinel) is _sentinel

# Alternative without sentinel object:
def my_is_empty(it):
    try:
        next(flatten(it))
    except StopIteration:
        return True
    return False
```

If you want to arbitrary nested iterables for greater applicability, not just `list`s, the code for `flatten` gets more complex, but `my_is_empty` remains unchanged.

Compared to [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53001063/364696), this is obviously more complex code, but it's also non-heuristic (so types with truly weird `repr`s can't fool it), more reusable for other purposes, and will be faster when most inputs are non-empty, especially if they're large (because it stops processing the instant it finds confirmation of non-empty status, wasting no time on the rest of the `list`).